# Error al implementar Apache Log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log, logger

Tengo que implementar `log` en mi programa, en principio solo para el uso de excepciones de `nivel error` y guardarlos en un fichero. Es la primera vez que los usos por lo que estoy bastante perdida.
Viendo tutoriales más o menos he visto como los usan.

Los log que usos son por cada una de las packages que tengo ya que es una combinación de **patrón MVC y DAO**

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.maven.tarea13DAO = ERROR, appenderTarea13DAO
log4j.logger.org.apache.maven.org.apache.maven.tarea13DAO.controlador = ERROR, appenderControlador
log4j.logger.org.apache.maven.org.apache.maven.tarea13DAO.modeloDAO = ERROR, appenderModeloDAO
log4j.logger.org.apache.maven.org.apache.maven.tarea13DAO.vistaDAO = ERROR, appenderVistaDAO

log4j.appender.appenderTarea13DAO=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderTarea13DAO.File=log/tarea13DAO.log
log4j.appender.appenderTarea13DAO.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appenderTarea13DAO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderTarea13DAO.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [ %-5p] [%c{1}:%L] %m%n

log4j.appender.appenderControlador=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderControlador.File=log/controlador.log
log4j.appender.appenderControlador.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appenderControlador.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderControlador.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [ %-5p] [%c{1}:%L] %m%n

log4j.appender.appenderModeloDAO=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderModeloDAO.File=log/modeloDAO.log
log4j.appender.appenderModeloDAO.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appenderModeloDAO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderModeloDAO.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [ %-5p] [%c{1}:%L] %m%n

log4j.appender.appenderVistaDAO=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderVistaDAO.File=log/vistaDAO.log
log4j.appender.appenderVistaDAO.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appenderVistaDAO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderVistaDAO.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [ %-5p] [%c{1}:%L] %m%n
```

Al ejecutarlo me salta este error, no se si es debido a que he hecho algo mal o tiene que ver con la versión, ya que en los tutoriales que vi no les saltaba dicho error.

**Error**

```
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tarea13DAO</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>tarea13DAO</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
        
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas usando una versión vieja que probablemente tiene muchos problemas de seguridad.

Te muestro lo que sería usar la versión 2.18 que es relativamente nueva.

En maven agrega las siguientes dependiencias al POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Luego en la carpeta de recursos creas un archivo xml con el nombre "log4j2.xml" como el siguiente, este es solo un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" name="MiProyectoConfig">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="debugFileName">error.log</Property>
        <Property name="infoFileName">info.log</Property>
        <Property name="traceFileName">warn.log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="infoFile" fileName="${infoFileName}">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="errorFile" fileName="${debugFileName}">
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="warnFile" fileName="${traceFileName}">
            <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="console">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="infoFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="errorFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="warnFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Es importante que este archivo de configuración vaya en la carpeta de recursos y no en una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta de recursos.

[image: Recursos]

Si vas a hacer testeos también va en los recursos para los testeos unitarios:

[image: Recursos para Testeos unitarios]

Luego en cada clase que quieras hacer un logueo creas una variable como la siguiente:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MiClase.class);
```

Las importaciones que hay que hacer son las siguientes:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

Finalmente para loguear llamas a los métodos según el nivel:

```
LOGGER.error(String.format("Ha ocurrido un error con el objeto %s.", objeto));

LOGGER.warn(String.format("El objeto %s es inesperado.", objeto));

LOGGER.fatal(String.format("Ha ocurrido un error fatal con el objeto %s.", objeto));

LOGGER.info(String.format("Objeto %s creado.", objeto));
```

Aprender como funciona log4j lleva tiempo, pero creo que te ahorré bastante con los ejemplos. Para seguir aprendiendo te recomiendo que vayas a la página de la [documentación](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html).

Comment: Si, tal y como dices es una versión antigua que tenía 5 fallos de vulnerabilidad. Dado que al crear el proyecto Maven no me sali la carpeta Sources la cree yo misma y ahí metí el archivo log.  Con el Código que has puesto se me crearía los log en un archivo XML o de texto?. Gracias

Comment: Es raro que no te aparezca esa carpeta. El archivo sería de texto. En realidad son varios archivos.